# default value comes first useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I'm using react-native-phone-number-input to have user's phone number. Also using expo location to get user's isoCountryCode, and then i set it to a variable by useState, however at the begin it comes as null so in the phone number section appears the default value, how can i catch it properly?

```
import PhoneInput, { PhoneInputProps } from 'react-native-phone-number-input';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
```

```
const [countryCode, setCountryCode] = useState<
    PhoneInputProps['defaultCode'] | string | null
  >();
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setCountryCode('GB');
        return;
      }
      const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      // await Location.isBackgroundLocationAvailableAsync()
      await (
        await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(location.coords)
      ).map((a) => setCountryCode(a.isoCountryCode)); <<< I catch the isoCountryCode here
    })();
  }, []);

  console.log('Country Code : ', countryCode);
...
```

```
<PhoneInput
      ref={childRef}
      value={value}
      defaultCode={countryCode ? countryCode : 'GB'} <<< It should be set here, but always default comes first
      textInputProps={{
        keyboardType: 'phone-pad',
        ...(props.textInputProps || {}),
      }}
      containerStyle={{ marginTop: 20, backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
      countryPickerButtonStyle={styles.countryPickerButtonStyle}
      textContainerStyle={styles.textContainer}
      flagButtonStyle={{}}
      textInputStyle={{}}
      codeTextStyle={{}}
      countryPickerProps={{
        ...(props.countryPickerProps || {}),
      }}
...
```

and console.log output

```
Country Code :  undefined
Country Code :  TR
```

Comment: This is completely expected, and it's not clear what the actual problem is (besides an `undefined` in the console, which in itself is no problem at all as users won't see it). If your component doesn't actually work, or looks wrong, with this state being `undefined`, consider showing some sort of loading indicator while you're still fetching the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value in your state is `undefined` and the code in the `useEffect` is async. Hence, it is expected that in the first render the value of the state is `undefined`. After a new state is set in the `useEffect`, a new render cycle will be run with the updated state value.

If you want to prevent this from happening you could either provide a default value (which might not make much sense if we are talking about locations here)

```js
const [countryCode, setCountryCode] = useState<
    PhoneInputProps['defaultCode'] | string | null
  >(‘SomeCode’);
```

Or you could use conditional rendering to wait until the location has been fetched as follows.

```js
const [countryCode, setCountryCode] = useState<
    PhoneInputProps['defaultCode'] | string | null
  >();
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setCountryCode('GB');
        return;
      }
      const location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      // await Location.isBackgroundLocationAvailableAsync()
      await (
        await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync(location.coords)
      ).map((a) => setCountryCode(a.isoCountryCode)); <<< I catch the isoCountryCode here
    })();
  }, []);

if (!countryCode) {
   return null
}

// else return phone input 

return (…)
```